# What is wrong with my make_unique, how do I implement to suit my usecase

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am have written a basic version of unique pointer in the code below. I have copied Herb Sutter's implementation of `make_unique()` and I am unable to make it work. I am getting an error:

**UPDATE:**
I have removed `using namespace std;`

```
D:\coding\cpp\smartPointers>g++ -std=c++11 uniquePtrImpl.cpp

uniquePtrImpl.cpp:33:41: error: expansion pattern 'Args&&' contains no argument packs

  UniquePointer make_unique(Args&&... args) {


uniquePtrImpl.cpp: In function 'UniquePointer make_unique()':

uniquePtrImpl.cpp:34:52: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope

   return UniquePointer(new T(std::forward(args) ...));


uniquePtrImpl.cpp:34:58: error: expansion pattern 'forward()' contains no argument packs

   return UniquePointer(new T(std::forward(args) ...));

uniquePtrImpl.cpp: In function 'int main()':

uniquePtrImpl.cpp:48:66: error: no matching function for call to 
'make_unique(const char [6], int)'

   UniquePointer aPerson = make_unique("Sweha", 25);


uniquePtrImpl.cpp:33:19: note: candidate: template UniquePointer make_unique()

  UniquePointer make_unique(Args&&... args) {


uniquePtrImpl.cpp:33:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:


uniquePtrImpl.cpp:48:66: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
   UniquePointer aPerson = make_unique("Sweha", 25);
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    Person(string const& name, int const& age): name{name}, age{age} { }
    void show() {
        cout << "Person's name is : " << name << " and age is : " << age << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class UniquePointer {
private:
    T *ptr;
public:
    explicit UniquePointer(T* p = nullptr): ptr{p} {}
    UniquePointer(UniquePointer const& up) = delete;
    UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer const& up) = delete;

    ~UniquePointer() { delete ptr; }

    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
};

template <typename T, typename Args>
UniquePointer<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return UniquePointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));
}

int main() {
    UniquePointer<string> sp(new string("Hello"));
    cout << *sp << endl;

    *sp = "Wassup";
    cout << *sp << endl;

    UniquePointer<Person> sPerson(new Person("Tousif", 28));

    sPerson->show();

    UniquePointer<Person> aPerson = make_unique<Person>("Sweha", 25);
    aPerson->show();

    return 0;
}
```

**SOLVED:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

struct Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    Person(string const& name, int const& age): name{name}, age{age} { }
    void show() {
        cout << "Person's name is : " << name << " and age is : " << age << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class UniquePointer {
private:
    T *ptr;
public:
    explicit UniquePointer(T* p = nullptr): ptr{p} {}

    UniquePointer(UniquePointer const& up) = delete;
    UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer const& up) = delete

    UniquePointer(UniquePointer&& up) {
        ptr = std::move(up.ptr);
    }

    UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer&& up){
        ptr = std::move(up.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    ~UniquePointer() { delete ptr; }

    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
};

template <typename T, typename...   Args>
UniquePointer<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return UniquePointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));
}

int main() {
    UniquePointer<string> sp(new string("Hello"));
    cout << *sp << endl;

    *sp = "Wassup";
    cout << *sp << endl;

    UniquePointer<Person> sPerson(new Person("Tousif", 28));

    sPerson->show();

    UniquePointer<Person> aPerson = make_unique<Person>("Sweha", 25);
    aPerson->show();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `using namespace std;` from your file.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T, typename Args> // <------
UniquePointer<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return UniquePointer<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args) ...));
}
```

Args is not arguments pack. 
Change to:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args> // <------
```

but then your code doesn't compile because moves operation are deleted (how do you want to get `UniquePointer` from `make_unique` without these operations?). These were deleted by default because you have defined copy operations.
Add

```
 UniquePointer(UniquePointer&&) = default;
 UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer&&) = default;
```

Comment: I have delete the copy constructor and copy assignment operator and not set them to default.
UniquePointer(UniquePointer const& up) = delete;
UniquePointer& operator=(UniquePointer const& up) = delete;

Comment: moves operation are generated by compiler default only if no copy operations were defined and destructor was not defined too. you have defined dtor so moves are deleted. you need to define these to return object from make_unique.

Comment: @Tousif I mean that by  ` = delete` for copy operations you have defined them :) So moves operations were not generated.